# How to implement conditional put in RocksDB?

Tags: sql, transactions, rocksdb, cockroachdb

In an earlier blog written by members of CockroachDB: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/sql-in-cockroachdb-mapping-table-data-to-key-value-storage/, the author states that CockroachDB's key-value API supports a `ConditionalPut(key, value, expected-value)`. Given that CockroachDB was built on RocksDB, how were they able to support conditional put?

Answer (score 1):

CockroachDB implements `ConditionalPut` using the same mechanism it uses for [ACID read-write transactions.](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/architecture/transaction-layer.html) Key-values are stored along with a multi-version concurrency control timestamp. To do a ConditionalPut, the storage client reads the existing value "as of" the same timestamp it's going to write the new value at. Since the write being discussed here is the write to a secondary index, there's already an implicit or explicit transaction happening, so there's no extra overhead beyond the read to check the precondition.

Comment: Just curious, how does CockroachDB prevent a write from happening before the read to check the precondition and the write? Does it hold an in-memory lock for that key?

Comment: Yup, at most one node holds a lease (enforced via distributed locks) for a given key at a time, and that node uses an in-memory lock.